# Highcharts not rendering small dataset

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a dataset I am trying to render, this is mostly just for exploring the controls.  However, I noticed that if I render data which only spans a couple of hours, the chart will not draw anything.  If I span the data over the course of a few days then it will draw.  I've tried adjusting both the `tickInterval (5)` and `pointInterval (3600 * 1000)` but I just can't seem to get this to draw.  Can anyone offer any possible suggestions?  Thank you!

```
window.chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        zoomType: 'x'
    },
    rangeSelector: {
        selected: 1
    },

    title: {
        text: 'AAPL Stock Price'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        pointInterval: 1000
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'AAPL Stock Price',
        data: [
                [Date.UTC(2006, 0, 29, 0, 0, 0), 30.14],
                [Date.UTC(2006, 0, 29, 0, 0, 0), 33.11],
                [Date.UTC(2006, 0, 29, 1, 0, 0), 34.76],
                [Date.UTC(2006, 0, 29, 1, 0, 0), 23.12],
                [Date.UTC(2006, 0, 29, 2, 0, 0), 34.34],
                [Date.UTC(2006, 0, 29, 2, 0, 0), 34.48],
                [Date.UTC(2006, 0, 29, 3, 0, 0), 33.9],
                [Date.UTC(2006, 0, 29, 3, 0, 0), 14.72]
            ]
    }]
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also create an additional series if you'd like to plot data points on the same date.

```
series: [
{
    name: 'AAPL Stock Price',
    data: [
        [Date.UTC(2006, 0, 29, 0, 0, 0), 30.14],
        [Date.UTC(2006, 0, 29, 1, 0, 0), 34.76],
        [Date.UTC(2006, 0, 29, 2, 0, 0), 34.34],
        [Date.UTC(2006, 0, 29, 3, 0, 0), 33.9]
    ]
},{
    name: 'AAPL Stock Price 2',
    data: [
        [Date.UTC(2006, 0, 29, 0, 0, 0), 33.11],
        [Date.UTC(2006, 0, 29, 1, 0, 0), 23.12],
        [Date.UTC(2006, 0, 29, 2, 0, 0), 34.48],
        [Date.UTC(2006, 0, 29, 3, 0, 0), 14.72]
    ]
}]
```

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple data points with the [same x-value](http://jsfiddle.net/PYVmj/):

```
[Date.UTC(2006, 0, 29, 0, 0, 0), 30.14],
[Date.UTC(2006, 0, 29, 0, 0, 0), 33.11],
```

These are both from Jan 29, 2006 at midnight.  If you make them [all distinct times](http://jsfiddle.net/PYVmj/1/), it will render.

Comment: Thanks all for your input...
@Dennis: Even though I have a couple data points with the same x value, shouldn't it still render at least something since all of the x values are not the same?

Comment: You're giving it bad input data; you can't expect it to do anything.

Comment: Thank you Dennis, I have accepted your response as an answer to this question.  It still seems to me though that if I have 10 data points and two of them happen to have the same x value that it should still render the rest of the points and completely break.  So what I will end up doing a "pre-process" event and remove and duplicate data points that have the same x value.  Please post a comment if anyone can think of a better way of doing this.  Thanks again!!

Comment: You have to consider what having two data points with the same x-value means in your model.  If you are doing stock prices, you've got one value per day.  How can a stock have two prices in one day?

Comment: I have the same problem with proper input data! Here is demo : [http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/intraday-area/](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/intraday-area/) Use abobe with option below : chart:{ zoomType: 'x' }, Then zoom a small range it will fail to display chart, it will display tooltip and points a bit but no chart, no area... Am i wrong ? If i am right then your response is not acceptable @Dennis :)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to disable dataGrouping, http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.series.dataGrouping

Comment: I tried your suggestion and also tried it in conjunction with forced: true and had no luck, still not plotting anything.